# Reading and Excel File into Pycharm

Tags: python, excel

so I am trying to follow along with a tutorial to figure out how to read an excel file into Pycharm. I have downloaded openpyxl, but I am having trouble making this work. I keep getting the same error.

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\GibbsFamily\\Desktop\\ExcelTutorial.xlsx")
print(type(wb))
```

This is what I am getting:

```
line 5
    def process_workbook(Excel Python Lesson):
                               ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like you shared the wrong line of code. `def process_workbook(Excel Python Lesson):` is not valid syntax. What are you attempting with `Excel Python Lesson`?

Comment: maybe also share the tutorial you are following with so we can better advise.. ?

Comment: Looks like the code you think you are running is not the code actually being run. Or at least the code example provided is not what you ran to get the error. The code you ran appears to have a function called 'process_workbook' defined as `def process_workbook(Excel Python Lesson):` which is not valid, the parameters 'Excel Python Lesson' need to be comma separated however I would guess that they are not what the function is expecting anyway. Probably it should be more along the lines of `def process_workbook(filename):`. If you do actually execute the sample code it should run OK.